# Change date color from a material DataPicker in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, material-design-in-xaml

I´m a little new using WPF, and i´m implementing the MaterialDesing library. I want to change the color of certain propierties of a DataPicker but cannot find where to do that. Specially the container that has the year, day and month (the one that is in blue)

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX6AR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `PrimaryHueMidBrush` resource:

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Calendar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCalendarPortrait}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Red" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</DatePicker>
```